# Deploy Cloned Servlet to Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, git, tomcat, servlets

I am a newbie to working with open-source. I am trying to build and modify a Servlet from git [here](https://github.com/BobSimons/erddap.git) but can not get it to build in eclipse and be hosted in a tomcat server.

When cloned the repo has the directory structure here

[image]

The web.xml is within the WEB-INF folder, its just too bit to see clearly so I cropped it.

From all of my reading the best way to get this server going was to create a blank 'Dynamic Web Project' in eclipse then copy all of the files in to it.

Doing so gives you the following directory structure for the project

[image]

My first thought was to copy the entire contents of WEB-INF from the repo into the WEB-INF folder of the new project. When I hit build it didn't do anything which was suspicious. Running the server it would give me a `500 error: Error Instantiating Servlet Class com.gov.noaa.pfel.erddap.Erddap`.

It is looking for the Erddap class you can see above. I kept fiddling with the web.xml to see if it could find it but I don't think that is the problem.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ERDDAP</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>gov.noaa.pfel.erddap.Erddap</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ERDDAP</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  <!-- this works for ERDDAP and ERDDAP2 -->
</servlet-mapping>
```

Do I need to copy the java files into the src folder in the project?

**EDIT**

I have done as was suggested by @iwlagn, moved all WEB-INF/classes to the src folder and

- download -> WebContent/download
- images -> WebContent/images
- public -> WebContent/public
- WEB-INF/* (except for classes) -> WebContent/WEB-INF

The project builds however I get a large number of errors.

[image]

**Is there another step that's needed?**

Comment: You need to reference contents of WebContent/WEB-INF/lib as libraries, but I don't remember how to do it in Eclipse (I'm IntelliJ user).
Also I would recommend you to use Maven or Gradle instead of plain Eclipse project, so eclipse can automatically pick all your dependencies

Comment: @iwlagn I made a maven project using this tutorial: http://crunchify.com/how-to-create-dynamic-web-project-using-maven-in-eclipse/      Do I follow your same step with copying?

Comment: Maven project has different structure, but eclipse may show it same. If yes - just do the same copying, omitting WEB-INF/lib. If no, mapping is following: WEB-INF/classes -> src/main/java, WEB-INF/* (except for classes and lib) -> src/main/webapp/WEB-INF, download -> src/main/webapp, images -> src/main/webapp, public -> src/main/webapp. Also you will need to edit your pom.xml to provide correct dependencies like
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.20</version>
</dependency>
which corresponds to JAR WEB-INF/lib/slf4j.jar

Comment: you will need to map every jar in WEB-INF/lib to <dependency></dependency>

Comment: @iwlagn the tutorial told me to use maven-webapp. Structure doesnt have a src/main/java folder but it does have src/main/resources. Is that the same?

Comment: @iwlagn also, some of the jar files in the lib are custom made from the person who developed the Repo I've cloned

Comment: just create missing folders. You can read how to use custom jar as maven dependencies here: http://blog.valdaris.com/post/custom-jar/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move everything from WEB-INF/classes to the src of your new project. Also, as far, as I understand structure of your initial project, you need to move files from it to the new project according to following mappings:

- download -> WebContent/download
- images -> WebContent/images
- public -> WebContent/public
- WEB-INF/* (except for classes) -> WebContent/WEB-INF

**EDIT** Contents of WebContent/WEB-INF/lib should be referenced as project libraries